# Sql pivot selection

Tags: sql-server

I got one table like this

```
DRID    ReceivedUser    ReceivedDate    JobOrder    Warranty    Service DeliveredUser   DeliveredDate   Active
1       abc             3/7/2017        78330       O           2       xyz             3/9/2017        N
2       abc             3/9/2017        93045       O           2       abc             3/9/2017        N
3       xyz             3/9/2017        10620       O           2       xyz             3/9/2017        N   
4       xyz             3/9/2017        11393       O           2                                       Y 
5       pqr             3/9/2017        12101       O           2       xyz             3/9/2017        N
6       xyz             3/9/2017        12545       I           2       pqr             3/9/2017        N
7       pqr             3/9/2017        13512       O           2       xyz             3/9/2017        N
8       xyz             3/9/2017        13642       I           2       xyz             3/9/2017        N
9       xyz             3/9/2017        15190       O           2       abc             3/9/2017        N
```

I am trying to select like this

```
Received    Warranty    Outwarranty Total
abc         0           2           2
xyz         2           3           5
pqr         0           2           2
```

but I am getting the result like this

```
Received    Warranty    Outwarranty Total
xyz         2           0           2
xyz         0           3           3
abc         0           2           2
pqr         0           2           2
```

My code

```
select ReceivedUser,Case WHEN Warranty='i' THEN COUNT(JobOrder) Else 0 END As Warranty,Case WHEN 
Warranty='O' THEN Count(JobOrder) ELSE 0 End AS OutWarranty,Count(JobOrder) As Total
 from DailyReceipt
 where CAST(ReceivedDate AS date)=GETDATE()
 Group By ReceivedUser,Warranty
```

Selecting data as per today date.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I can't read your data, and also your logic for aggregating warranties is unclear.

Comment: @jacky my first selection, but am getting warranty and outwarranty separate row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need this:

```
select ReceivedUser,sum(Case WHEN Warranty='i' THEN 1 Else 0 END) As Warranty,sum(Case WHEN 
Warranty='O' THEN 1 ELSE 0 End) AS OutWarranty,Count(JobOrder) As Total
from DailyReceipt
where CAST(ReceivedDate AS date)=GETDATE()
Group By ReceivedUser
```

[Example](http://rextester.com/GKXCDD58642)

Comment: i tried this getting error "is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: dailyreceipt.warranty

Comment: Sorry James it is my mistake, your code is working just fine. really helpful. thanks.